# What is Genga exactly?

Tags: naruto, one-piece, anime-production

I've been seeing a lot of "Genga" on eBay and I know it means "Original Art" but is genga actually like the ORIGINAL ORIGINAL art like drawn by hand by the artist then packaged and sold? or is Genga copies and prints of original art.

I know some genga for sure is just prints but is all genga just prints? Like in these images are they actually the one of a kind original art or just a print of the original art.

[image: Genga from One Piece]
[image: Genga from Naruto]

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to an animation cel used in western animation. They're one of a kind collector's items and are worth a lot of money. They serve as the base for the animation.